# How to use sliding window

Tags: c, buffer

I'm making LZ77 compression algorithm and i can't understand how to implement sliding window, and how to write information to the buffer, and then shift it.
I have some code

```
int encode(const char *infile_path, const char *outfile_path, unsigned sb_size, unsigned la_size)
{
    FILE *infile = NULL, *outfile = NULL;
    if (bread_file(&infile, infile_path) || bwrite_file(&outfile, outfile_path)) {
        return -1;
    }

    size_t win_size = sb_size + la_size;
    char *window = malloc(sizeof * window * win_size);
    if (window == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s() error: Memory allocation failure!\n", __func__);
        return -1;
    }

    size_t buf_size;
    buf_size = fread(window + sb_size, sizeof(char), win_size - sb_size, infile);
    if (feof(infile)) {
        printf("EOF has been reached!\n");
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s() error: Couldn't read info from the file!\n\n", __func__);
        return -1;
    }
}
```

I'm stuck here. Could you advise any detailed information on this?

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: @MayurK As i know i should devide my window into two parts: `search_buf` and `lookahead`. Then i need  to `fread()` some data from a file to the window, i.e to the `lookahead` and then shit the window and fill `search_buf` up. I guess i get it wrong, and i need some info to clarify it.

Comment: I would suggest first you read about algorithm and get the clarity on the requirement. Otherwise it will be difficult to code. In the code you have shared there is no mention about `search_buf` or `lookahead`.